# Get Checked Item in Check Box Column in Data Grid View - C# Windows form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to load the Checked Value in the column Status if the Value in the Attendance_Status = "Attended"
and uncheck if the value is Unattended.

Below is the screen shot of the form:

[image]

I am trying to add the code below but it doesn't work:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows) {
    if (row.Cells["Attendance_Status"].Value == "Attendance") 
    {
        row.Cells["Status"].Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells["Status"].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: I'm confused as to where the image is from. Is it HTML?

Comment: if (row.Cells["Attendance_Status"].Value == "Attendance")  change to "Attended"

Comment: The if/else can be avoided by doing `row.Cells["Status"].Selected = row.Cells["Attendance_Status"].Value == "Attended"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with finding the control in the gridview and then the value of that checked either 0 or 1 based on whether it is selected or not as shown below.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvGridview.Rows)
{
  CheckBox cbAddAction = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAddAction");                     
  int addPermission = Convert.ToInt16(cbAddAction.Checked);
}
```

You can check the below gridview definition/declaration for more help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserPermission" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        OnRowDataBound="gvUserPermission_RowDataBound" PageSize="50" 
        DataKeyNames="ModuleId" 
        onselectedindexchanged="gvUserPermission_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="« First" LastPageText="Last »" Mode="NumericFirstLast"
            PageButtonCount="10" />
        <Columns>                                               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Modulename" HeaderText="Module Name" ItemStyle-Width="450px"
           SortExpression="Modulename" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Action">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddAction" Checked='<%# Eval("AddAction") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AddAction")) %>'
         runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                             
        </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

To load the data you can use the following method. It will check the value as per the data without any additional loop.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Action">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditAction" Checked='<%# Eval("EditAction") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("EditAction")) %>'
    runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your SQL Server datasource write a case statement to return `NULL` for values which is not `Attended` as given below.

```
create table Attendace (Id int, Attendance_Status Varchar(50))
insert into Attendace values (1, 'Attended'),
       (2, 'Not Attended')

select id
     , case Attendance_Status when 'Attended' then 1 else null
    end as Attendance_Status
from Attendace
```

Comment: I am using Windows form, I am not good at ASP. Can you help in Csharp Code.